# WP8.1 change application tile background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am wirking on windows phone 8.1 RT application. And i can't find a way to update background of application main tile.
code like this works only for secondary tiles:

```
foreach (SecondaryTile tile in await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync())
{
  tile.BackgroundColor = Colors.Aqua;
  tile.UpdateAsync();
}
```

I can get access to main tile only this way:

```
var updatile = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);
updatile.Update(tileNotification);
```

But i don't know how to change tile background this way.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you'll not be able to change the application tile's background color as you have requested, but where as you can include an image to the tile:

```
var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText01);
var tileImage = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0] as XmlElement;
tileImage.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/bild.JPG");
var tileText = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");  
var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileXml);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

Reference: [Live Tiles for WP8.1](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles/)

Comment: Yes, I think you right. Unfortunately I didn't find another way to do it. But additionaly you need to change TileSquare71x71 background image, and 150x300 if you support it.